# Is rewrite module appropriate for proxying different expressjs routes from nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have an expressjs node server running in a docker container. For this example it has only 1 route: GET `/user` that returns a simple JSON object.

I also have a nginx server proxying this express server using:

```
location /api {
    rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://nodeapp:3000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

In my `index.js` I make an XMLHttpRequest using the url `/api/user`.

Is the rewrite module, `rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;`, a valid solution to proxying the route in my express app? Are there any other alternatives? While this does work something seems "off" to me having to use regular expressions for something like this. I don't do devops work and only toy around with nginx so if there is a better solution I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple addition of a trailing slash on your location should make `nginx` perform the same transform implicitly.

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://nodeapp:3000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: Wow. That easy huh? Thank you. I actually read that documentation but didn't pick up on the trailing slash on the uri.